# Finding relationship of dichotomous variable to ordinal variable (in R)

Tags: binary-data, ordinal-data

As stated above - I'm trying to find a relationship of dichotomous outcome variable (TRUE or FALSE) to an ordinal variable (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) (in R). The ordinal variable indicates increasing amounts of urbanization. I want to see if there is a positive relationship between urbanization and the outcome variable. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Logistic regression would be the easy answer (Using glm() and family = "Binomial" in R). However, logistic regression would treat the ordinal variable as a continuous variable, which might not be the worst thing.

Comment: @Greenparker I tended towards this answer with `glm(formula = Outcome ~ Rurality, family = binomial, data = df)` - I was wondering if this is appropriate, if any adjustment in the ordinal variable is needed, if there's a more appropriate solution? I also get a negative intercept value, I'm not sure how to interpret this, as I'd imagine the outcome is 0,1. I am unsure how to "fix" this occurrence or explain it.

Comment: Its not perfect, but it might still be appropriate since theoretically, no assumptions are imposed on the distribution of the predictors. I am not aware of another fix for this.

Comment: While not being very "formal," would it not be suitable for your purposes to simply plot the frequency distribution for the true and false cases separately and look for a shift?

Comment: @dsaxton i do see it, but looking for a formal approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to treat the integers $\{ 1, \ldots , 9 \}$ as the categories themselves and do a two sample test to see if the mean for one distribution is larger than the mean for the other (a $t$ test perhaps if you have large samples).

A nonparametric alternative would be to perform a rank sum test to see if the categories in the "true" sample (I'll assume that this is the sample containing larger values) tend to be larger than those in the false sample.  To do this you would combine both samples (keeping track of which sample each observation came from), sort them and then assign the ranks in the sorted sample to each observation.  When you have ties use the average rank instead.

After this sum the ranks of the observations in the true sample and use this as your test statistic.  For large samples this rank sum will have an approximate normal distribution, but if you aren't comfortable using such an approximation you can empirically estimate the null distribution using a permutation idea.  Here is some R code that would do this:

```
# true sample here
sample1 = c(2, 7, 4, 8, 5, 6, 2, 2, 5, 7)
# false sample here
sample2 = c(7, 1, 5, 3, 9, 8, 1, 1, 1, 8)

# combine into a data frame and calculate the ranks
data = data.frame(value = c(sample1, sample2),
                  rank = rank(c(sample1, sample2)),
                  sample = c(rep('true', length(sample1), rep('false', length(sample2)))

# calculate the test statistic
test_statistic = sum(data[data$sample == 'true', 'rank'])

# empirically estimate the null distribution of the test statistic,
# here we're conditioning on the values in sample1 and sample2
# and randomly permuting their assignment to the different groups
m = 10000
null_sample = NULL

for (i in 1:m) {
    null_sample[i] = sum(data[sample(1:(length(sample1) + length(sample2)),
                                     size=length(sample1), replace=FALSE),
                              'rank'])
}

# estimate the p-value for test_statistic and the null that
# sample1 came from a distribution with larger values than sample2
mean(test_statistic > null_sample)
```

Comment: Good idea, I'll probably use `t.test(d1, d2)`, not sure why I was so stuck on glm. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped.  The $t$ test approach is actually closely related to generalized linear models anyways.